# MySQL query from a query result in php

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

How should I go if I wanted to query a query result in php?
Supose I have this..

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_x WHERE tbl_x.attribute = y");
```

And now I need to query that $result to filter the results I got from its query. Note that I don't want to do this...

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM tbl_x WHERE tbl_x.attribute = y ) AS tbl_x1 WHERE tbl_x1... etc");
```

The reason I want to avoid that is I'm getting a "Duplicate column" error when executing a query like that.

I'm looking for something like...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_x");
$result2 = mysql_query_result($result);
```

Comment: Some sample output and exactly how you want to filter it would be great. There is no way to filter it using SQL after you've retrieved it, but you can filter it using PHP array functions.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, can't you just add some conditions to the original query?

Comment: First things first, you should not use select *. Always be explicit with whatever columns you want to find. Further, you're getting duplicates because you aren't using aliasing.

Comment: Why do you want to make a two step filter? Isn't it possible to do it at the first step? Why do you imagine to have duplicate column with your syntax?

Comment: this is the scenario: I have a table items a table configs and a table attributes (items has many configs, configs has many attr), I fill some combos with the attribute values for each item. So I have a first combo in which I display an attribute and its possible values from all the configurations belonging to that item that have attribute corresponding to that combo, a second combo should load attribute values depending on the first combo's selection, and so on. Since the number of attributes (or combos) isnt fixed I cant create a separate query for each

Comment: so I guessed maybe narrowing the search results should be the way to go... cause I can fetch all the configs and its attributes belonging to that item and then filter them depending on the attribute type and the attributes values selected before ( For example if you select size: M on the first combo, the second combo should only display the colours available in size M, and once I select a colour, i.e. green, the third combo should display lets say cloth types available for that item in size M and colour green)

Answer (score 2):

You can apply more than one term in your search conditions, separated by `AND`:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_x 
                       WHERE tbl_x.attribute = y 
                         AND tbl_x.attribute2 = z");
```

---

Re your comments above.  It sounds like you are using the [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) design.

In order to match multiple attributes, you have to do some tricks.  Normally, a WHERE clause can only apply to one row at a time.  But since each of your attributes are stored on separate rows, you need to do either one of two solutions:

1. Join multiple rows into one row, so you can use WHERE on all attributes in one condition.

   ```
   SELECT config_id
   FROM attributes AS s
   JOIN attributes AS c USING (config_id)
   JOIN attributes AS l USING (config_id)
   WHERE (s.attr, s.value) = ('size', 'M')
   AND (c.attr, c.value) = ('colour, 'green')
   AND (l.attr, l.value) = ('cloth', 'cotton);
   ```
2. Search for any of the several attributes, and then if the number of rows that match is equal to the number of attributes you were searching for, you've found them all.

   ```
   SELECT config_id
   FROM attributes
   WHERE (attr, value) = ('size', 'M') 
   OR (attr, value) = ('colour', 'green') 
   OR (attr, value) = ('cloth', 'cotton')
   GROUP BY config_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT attr) = 3;
   ```

Comment: read the comment above for further info on my problem pls :), I know I can add more search conditions, just was setting an example... maybe I wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 0):

You can still have your query of query without getting "duplicate column" error. Just alias and name the columns

```
 $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT tbl_x1.col1, tbl_x1.col2,...etc  FROM 
            (SELECT * FROM tbl_x WHERE tbl_x.attribute = y) AS tbl_x1 
             WHERE tbl_x1... etc");
```

Comment: the problem is my sql sentence is being put together dynamically, and I don't know how many times it will be nested, actually it may not even be nested at all.. I can't think of a way around this problem using aliases (not saying there is none though)